# Referencing a capture group inside the search regex of IntelliJ

Tags: regex, intellij-idea, replace, regex-group, jetbrains-ide

### Talking about the Replace in Path tool of IntelliJ, WebStorm, etc, using regular expressions.

I know you can reference a capture-group inside the *replacement* string in IntelliJ like `$n` where `n` is the index of the capture-group.

For example, you could do the following find-replace operation:

```regex
Find:    <Foo key=\{([a-z]+)\.key\} />
Replace: <Bar color=\{$1.color\} />
```

Which would change these kinds of lines:

```
<Foo key={something.key} />
```

into:

```
<Bar color={something.color} />
```

---

**But what if you wanted to find pairs of elements like so:**

```
<Foo key={something.key} />
<Bar color={something.color} />
```

and replace them with:

```
<FooBar el={something} />
```

How can I reference the capture-group inside the *search* string?

I have tried many options like:

```regex
<Foo key=\{([a-z]+)\.key\} />\s*<Bar color=\{$1\.color\} />
```

but the **reference** (`$1`) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just figured it out by trying. In the *search* string you can reference a capture-group with `\n` where `n` is the index.

In this case, the search string would have to be:

```
<Foo key=\{([a-z]+)\.key\} />\s*<Bar color=\{\1\.color\} />
```

Whereas, the replace string would have to be:

```
<FooBar el=\{$1\} />
```

Wierd that they'd be referenced differently.